# Runtime Exception with the method

Tags: java

I'm pretty much done with the code and all of the test cases are giving me correct except two where an array is empty and should throw a Runtime exception with the message "Empty array has no mode". My test failure says: Empty input should yield a RuntimeExcetpion with message "Empty array has no mode". I've included that in the code but still failing those test cases. One of the test cases is:

```
@Test(timeout=2000) public void mode_empty1(){
    String msg;
    String expect = "Empty array has no mode";
    try{
      Mode.mode(new String[]{});
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e){
      String actual = e.getMessage();
      msg = String.format("\nRuntimeException has wrong message\nExpect: %s\nActual: %s\n",
                          expect,actual);
      assertEquals(msg,expect,actual);
      return;
    }
    msg = String.format("\nEmpty input should yield a RuntimException with message '%s'\n",
                        expect);
    fail(msg);
  }
```

Coulb smb please help?

```
public class Mode {

    public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[])
    {
        try
            {

            if(items == null) throw new RuntimeException("Empty array has no mode");

            else
            {
                T element = items[0];
                int count = 0;

                for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
                {
                    int tempCount = 0;
                    T tempElement = items[i];

                    for(int j = 0; j < items.length; j++)
                        {
                            if(tempElement.equals(items[j]))
                                tempCount++;
                        }   
                    if(tempCount > count)
                    {
                        count = tempCount;
                        element = tempElement;
                    }
                }
                return new Pair<T, Integer>(element, new Integer(count));
            }


        }

        catch(RuntimeException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 

        }


    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: You'd get the exception if you passed in `null` instead of `new String[] {}`, or checked for `items.length == 0` instead of/as well as `items == null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `if(items == null)` tests if the array is `null`, not if it is empty. But when you do `Mode.mode(new String[]{})` you pass an empty array, not `null`.

You can either check for an empty array by doing:

```
if(items == null || items.length == 0) throw new RuntimeException("Empty array has no mode");
```

Or pass a `null` to `Mode.mode()`:

```
Mode.mode(null)
```

Since you want to catch the `RuntimeException` outside `mode()` you don't really need the `try-catch` block anymore:

```
public static <T> Pair<T, Integer> mode(T items[]) {
    if (items == null || items.length == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Empty array has no mode");
    } else {
        T element = items[0];
        int count = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            int tempCount = 0;
            T tempElement = items[i];

            for(int j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                if (tempElement.equals(items[j])) {
                    tempCount++;
                }
            }   
            if (tempCount > count) {
                count = tempCount;
                element = tempElement;
            }
        }
        return new Pair<T, Integer>(element, new Integer(count));
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did before, if(items == null || items.length == 0).. still not working

Comment: Thanks, Anderson! I got it! Btw, do I really need that try-catch method once I moved if-condition outside try-catch?

Comment: Glad to help! I think removing the `try-catch` block should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Your production code checks for a null input, but your test code passes in a non-null input.

You should either change the test code to pass in a null input:

```
Mode.mode(null);
```

or change the condition in your production code to:

```
if(items.length == 0) throw ...
```

You might want to check both nullity and emptiness in your production code:

```
if(items == null || items.length == 0) throw ...
```

You will also need to move this check before the `try` block, since you are immediately catching the thrown exception.

```
if(items == null) throw new RuntimeException("Empty array has no mode");
try {
  ...
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, and move the check before the try block. You're catching the RuntimeException, so the exception never makes it out of the method throwing it.

Comment: What do you mean by "move the check outside" ??